# Table score soccer

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables: the club, goals and point. When I worked the sum of goals and points it gave me the doubled results. I looked for a solution [MySQL doubled results using sum and left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607009/mysql-doubled-results-using-sum-and-left-join), but we now showing: 1054 - Unknown column 'b.idKlub' in 'on clause' SQL=SELECT... where is my error?

```
SELECT
k.imeKluba, 
b.odigrano_kola, b.pobeda, b.nereseno, b.izgubljeno, b.ukupni_bodovi,
g.dati_golovi, g.primljeni_golovi, g.razlika_golovi
FROM #__fudbal_klubovi AS k 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
        COUNT( idKolo) AS odigrano_kola,
        COUNT(IF(bodovi = 3, 1, NULL)) AS pobeda, 
        COUNT(IF(bodovi = 1, 1, NULL)) AS nereseno, 
        COUNT(IF(bodovi = 0, 1, NULL)) AS izgubljeno, 
        SUM(bodovi) AS ukupni_bodovi
    FROM #__fudbal_bodovi
    GROUP BY idKlub) AS b
    ON b.idKlub = k.idKlub 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
        SUM(go) AS dati_golovi,
        SUM(go_p) AS primljeni_golovi,
        SUM(go) - SUM(go_p) AS razlika_golovi
    FROM #__fudbal_gol
    GROUP BY idKlub) AS g
    ON g.idKlub = k.idKlub
```

Comment: in the sub-select `b` you simply have no column called idKlub! You group by it, but you don't select it.

Comment: Same will happen on subselect g... you need include the column `SELECT idKulub, COUNT ....`